# While loop not working correctly

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to show some infos, and I want to create a div only once, and after that just display the content

```
<?php while ( $loop1->have_posts() ) : $loop1->the_post(); ?>
<?php if($cnt == 0): echo "<div class=\"big-image\">";endif; ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'details_artists_image',true);?>" height="414" width="810" style="display:none"/>
<?php if($cnt ==0): echo "</div><!--end big-image--><ul class=\"artiesten-thumbs clearfix\">";endif; ?>
 <li>
    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'details_artists_image',true);?>"><img width="99" height="99" src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'details_artists_image',true);?>" alt=""></a>
    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
</li>
 <?php $cnt++; endwhile; ?>
 </ul>
```

The problem is that the output looks like this:

```
<div class="big-image"><img src="url" ... /></div>
<ul class="artiesten-thumbs">
<li>
<a href="url"><img width="99" height="99" src="url" alt=""></a>
<span>LP &#038; BRUGE</span>
</li>
<img again that should be in <div class="big-image"
<li>
<a href="url"><img width="99" height="99" src="url" alt=""></a>
<span>LP &#038; BRUGE</span>
</li>
<img again that should be in <div class="big-image"
```

So it doesn't show the images that should be in the div, it shows them one by one, after each `<li>`

Comment: Wow this is really confusing, but i think what you are going to want to do is run the while loop twice, once for the images, once for the content. Or just separate the html strings into 2 variables while in the loop using one for images and the other for content. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the image on every iteration. You want something like this

```
<?php if($cnt == 0) : ?>
    <div class="big-image">
        <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'details_artists_image',true);?>" height="414" width="810" style="display:none"/>
    </div><!--end big-image-->

    <ul class="artiesten-thumbs clearfix">
<?php endif; ?>
```